# Why is EF Core 2.0 generating multiple duplicate SQL statements?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I inherited a project with Entity Framework Core 2.0 in its service layer. I've never been much of a fan of EF so I've not worked with it very much at all. While trying to debug a performance issue for the client I turned on verbose logging so I could see all the SQL that EF was generating behind the scenes. When I looked into these logs I saw the same exact SQL statements appearing several times in succession. For example, I see the following query appearing six times in a row as part of a method that is retrieving the initial User login and then fetching their related profile info etc:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (114ms) [Parameters=[@__get_Item_0='1'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(1) [e].[Id], [e].[AccountId], [e].[Created], [e].[Email], [e].[Puk], [e].[LastModified], [e].[LastSync], [e].[PasswordHash], [e].[PasswordSalt], [e].[Status], [e].[Type]
FROM [Users] AS [e]
WHERE [e].[Id] = @__get_Item_0
```

Is this accurate? Is it really executing this same SQL 6 times as it says!?
What could possibly be causing this behavior?
Thank you very much for any insight you can provide.

*Note: that @__get_Item_0 parameter has the same exact value for each query

EDIT: adding the LINQ that is on the query object:

```
query.Include(x => x.UserProfile)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastModified)
.Take(resultsCount).ToList(); //resultsCount is set to 30
```

Comment: "What could possibly be causing this behavior?" a loop? multiple sessions? a logic flaw where the results are queried again instead of re-used? How confident are you that this is the source of the performance problem?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio ships with a built-in profiler. Use it.

Comment: @DStanley There is no loop in the code that would account for this, and stepping through it, it is only executing the relevant part once.

Comment: Does all of them contain _"Information: Executed DbCommand"_ or this part of the log actually differs?

Comment: So, where is LINQ expression?

Comment: @GuruStron YES! That was the part that alarmed me, is that they each have a slightly different timestamp in the log and they each say they executed it, just can't figure out why its doing that...there is no loop and stepping thru the code its not executing that block multiple times

Comment: @snappymcsnap I see you are running in the debug mode. I believe that can affect things - i.e. debugger can evaluate your code multiple times. What IDE are you using? Try enabling db queries logging for release mode and run code the release configuration to confirm.

Comment: @GuruStron VisualStudio 2019

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Added the LINQ to the initial question, thanks

Comment: Can you show how you build `query` object, because query you showed and generated sql query has nothing in common. Logs shows the query with user id as parameter, but LINQ query doesn't have such. Are you sure that logged query generated by the LINQ query you showed?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let me start by saying someone was using a really broken version there - 2.0 is awful, gets not much better with 2.1.... anyhow....

If you see multiple repeated statements like this then this can only have 2 reasons:

- The tracing is broken and shows the same output multiple times. Not that I have never seen that.
- The same query is repeated over and over.

Ef Core is NOT in the business of asking the server multiple times the same question without a reason.

if you can rule out 1 - time to add a breakpoint and see where these multiple requests originate in the code.

Comment: I have no reason to suspect the tracing is not correct. And stepping thru I'm not seeing the same code being executed multiple times. The query they build for the User though has an Include(u => u.UserProfile) and a Take(resultCount) as part of its construction, is that something to look into?

Comment: Nope. CONSTRUCTING a query does not EXECUTE it. If you see that happening multiple times - with the same user id in it - then either you have a trace error, or the code is executing it multiple times. PERIOD. THis is like the only LOGICAL solutions. If the variable is different -> then it is not the same query.

Comment: This may be the query being executed independently in various stages of processing. We do not know - THIS is where debugging comes in. Breakpoint. Find out wher ethe query is actually executed.